# How to sum data in array of JSON that get from controller when we compact to the view (Laravel)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, laravel

I am facing an issue. In the JSON array given below:

```
$results = [
{ 
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: income,
    amount: "1000"
},
{
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: expend,
    amount: "-2000"
},
{
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: initiall,
    amount: "3000"
},
{
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: income,
    amount: "4000"
},
{
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: expend,
    amount: "-5000"
},
{
    proj_name: rental,
    act_name: initial,
    amount:"6000"
},
{ 
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: income,
    amount: "7000"
},
{
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: expend,
    amount: "-8000"
},
{
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: initial,
    amount: "9000"
},
{
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: income,
    amount: "10000"
},
{
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: expend,
    amount: "-11000"
},
{
    proj_name: loan,
    act_name: initial,
    amount:"12000"
}
]
```

We can see here we have two `proj_name` as `rental` and `loan`.

Also transactions are categorized further with in 3 activities as `income`, `expend` and `initial`.

My question is how i can loop through `$results` array to calculate sum for each transaction type that i listed above. I would like the output to be like this:

```
|------------------|
|      rental      |
|------------------|
|income : 5000     |
|expend : -7000    |
|initial : 9000    |
|------------------|
|Sum Rental: 7000  |
|------------------|
|
|------------------|
|      loan        |
|------------------|
|income : 17000    |
|expend : -19000   |
|initial : 21000   |
|------------------|
|Sum Loan: 19000   |
|------------------|
```

Comment: Decode the JSON into an array then use one of PHP's many array functions to reduce that array into a single number, might I suggest `array_reduce()`.

Comment: Please can you implement it? I can't figure out how it will be.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON array had been decoded into `$json`, the following should work.

```
$output = [];    

foreach ($json as $item) {
    if (!isset($output[$item->proj_name])) {
        $output[$item->proj_name] = [
            'income' => 0,
            'expend' => 0,
            'initial' => 0,
            'total' => 0
        ];
    }
    $output[$item->proj_name][$item->act_name] += $item->amount;
}    

foreach ($output as $type) {
    $type['total'] = $type['initial'] + $type['income'] - $type['expend'];
}
```

It might need some minor tweaks, but that should iterate over your JSON array and increase each value by any items that match.

Comment: Thank for given answer, I did implement it but it not work even I can understand the logical of your answer...... Could you please make it more clear to figure out your answer......

Comment: What didn't work about it? Did you get an error at all?

Comment: Working on your answer, that's fix array for `$output` imaging that we have more than 2 `proj_name`, Thank you....

Comment: I've updated the code to programmatically build the proj_names into the output array, see if that works better.

Comment: Wow.... That's pretty good, Thanks for follow up, the value of `income`, `expend ` and `initial` working fine but sum of `total` still not work it in 0. 

Can you make up the array in this form:
`
$output = 
{
{
    proj_name: "rental",
    Income: 5000,
    Expend: -7000,
    Initial: 9000,
    Total: 7000
},
{
    proj_name: "loan",
    Income: 17000,
    Expend: -19000,
    Initial: 21000,
    Total: 19000
}
}
`
I tried to change but I fail I got confuse index of the array